# website screen resolution auto resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, wordpress

I have a website, its uses the 960 grid system, everything is fine.

Except the header, the header is too tall!

Is it possible to reduce the entire website size when the user's screen is less than or equal to 1024x768 ?

(same way you can press CTRL+ and CTRL- in IE?)

Comment: If the header is too tall, then decrease the height of the header. Why do you need to decrease the size of the whole site?

Comment: The website has been completed already, and decreasing the size of the header, would destroy the current design.

Comment: Are you using any background images? There's no widely supported way to shrink background images yet. So, you cannot simulate CTRL+/- by just setting CSS rules.

Comment: You need to provide us with some code/screenshots of what you're doing - most of us here would agree that such a radical solution (whole page resizing) probably be an overkill. Perhaps you only need to selectively resize one or two elements to make it work.

Comment: If it was me, i would just reduce the header, problem solved. but this isn't my website so i have to figure out otherways to fix it without killing their design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does support the non-standard [zoom style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(VS.85).aspx), which you could apply to the `<body>` if you detect the window size is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is possible, but I would advise against using such non-conventional approaches. I would just use a short header that will look good both in <= 768 and > 768.

After the document is loaded, you could check (using JavaScript) the client height of the body and apply a style to your `<body>` element (or just the header) to set the font size to a certain percentage. All your other dimensions would have to defined in em or percentage units so that the base size at the main container propagates to child elements.